# Profile popup window overlay doesn't fully cover screen on moblie

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, mobile-web, popups

When I open any pop-up window (badge tracker/viewer, WB hat selection, etc) on the profile page window on an iPad (using Safari) I get to look at this *ugly* setup:

[image: Overlay doesn’t cover the screen fully!]
<sup>See a not marked-up image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0nqm.jpg).</sup>

The problem is easily visible: The overlay that should cover the whole screen stops short. This is something that is really annoying. I imagine that this would be an easy fix in the CSS, just a change to the `width` tag’s value.

You can see that the problem is also seen on vertical orientation [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAHXu.jpg) (with markup) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAwpv.jpg) (without markup).

#### Could we please fix this?

Comment: I can even reproduce the problem on my iPhone SE using Chrome.

Comment: seems to be reproducable when chrome is minimized on windows 10 as well.